# How to quickly create dummy variables from list in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

So I am new to using R and I am having trouble with a rather simple task. I have a df called "Data" as follows...

```
           Group       Score.Diff
Row 1   Kyle, Steve      15
Row 2   Matthew, Tony    12 
...     ...              ...            
Row n   Anthony, Zack    -10
```

I also have a vector called "Player.Names" of all unique names that occur at some point in Data$Group like so...

```
        Names
Row 1   Anthony
Row 2   Kyle
...     ...
Row n   Zack
```

What I am struggling to accomplish is to create new columns in "Data" that represent each unique name and contain a value of 1 if the name is in Data$Group and a value of 0 if it is not. The desired output is shown below...

```
           Group       Score.Diff  Anthony  Kyle  Steve ...  Zack
Row 1   Kyle, Steve      15           0      1     1    ...   0
Row 2   Matthew, Tony    12           0      0     0    ...   0
...     ...              ...         ...    ...   ...   ...  ...
Row n   Anthony, Zack    -10          1      0     0    ...   1
```

Comment: You should really avoid having columns with multiple values per row. This is your second question with comma delimited values inside a column. You might want to read up on [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). If you have tidy data it makes working with data in R much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grepl` with patterns as the 'Names' column in 'df2' (looped with `sapply`) to return a logical vector for the 'Group' column, coerce to binary with `as.integer` and `cbind` with the first dataset ('df1').

```
cbind(df1, sapply(df2$Names, function(x) as.integer(grepl(x, df1$Group))))
#               Group Score.Diff Anthony Kyle Zack
#Row 1   Kyle, Steve         15       0    1    0
#Row 2 Matthew, Tony         12       0    0    0
#Row n Anthony, Zack        -10       1    0    1
```

###data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("Kyle, Steve", "Matthew, Tony",
 "Anthony, Zack"
), Score.Diff = c(15L, 12L, -10L)), .Names = c("Group", "Score.Diff"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Row 1", "Row 2", "Row n"))

df2 <- structure(list(Names = c("Anthony", "Kyle", "Zack")), 
   .Names = "Names", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Row 1", "Row 2",  "Row n"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DeJay No problem.  Glad to help you.